# Библиотеки для генерации .doc или .rtf файлов

Tags: java, android, поиск-библиотек

Cуществуют ли бесплатные библиотеки для Android (Java) для генерации *.doc или *.rtf файлов?

Comment: Для работы с документами Microsoft есть Java-библиотека [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: Для чисто JAVA все ОК Apache POI с андроидом не дружит из-за одинаковых классов в ней..

Comment: Вот тут есть пример проекта, как использовать Apache POI на Андроид: https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android

Comment: Буду пробовать с файлами *.XLS проблем не было вот *.DOC да... может в последней версии Apache POI устранили проблему. (т.к. года 4 тому назад она была)

Answer (score 1):

> Примечание от автора: этот ответ был [взят из комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/3069#3069) @Vadik Sirekanyan, поэтому был сделан [общим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

Для работы с документами `Microsoft` есть `Java`-библиотека [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). Вот [пример](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android) проекта, как использовать `Apache POI` на Андроид.